# Add a bound ComboBox column to a DataGridColumn at runtime

Tags: wpf, datagrid, combobox

I'd like to display a DataGrid which will contain data I've uploaded from a data source into a DataTable.  The columns will be different each time and some will need to be represented using a ComboBox.

How do I go about setting the DataGridTemplateColumn for a column, that needs a ComboBox, at runtime?

Ok, this is the closest I've got with the help of @Meleak, almost there, just displaying the key rather than the value when the grid is not being edited.

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Dictionary MyDictionary { get; set; }

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Init Dictionary
    this.MyDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    this.MyDictionary.Add(1, "Value 1");
    this.MyDictionary.Add(2, "Value 2");
    this.MyDictionary.Add(3, "Value 3");

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    DataColumn column = new DataColumn("MyTypeId", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add(column);

    DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
    newRow["MyTypeId"] = 1;

    dt.Rows.Add(newRow);

    dataGrid.Columns.Add(GetNewComboBoxColumn("My Type", "MyTypeId", this.MyDictionary));

    this.DataContext = dt;
}

public static DataGridTemplateColumn GetNewComboBoxColumn(string header,
                                                  string bindingPath,
                                                  object itemsSource)
{
    DataGridTemplateColumn comboBoxColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
    comboBoxColumn.Header = header;

    Binding textBinding = new Binding();
    textBinding.Path = new PropertyPath(bindingPath);

    FrameworkElementFactory textBlock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
    textBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.MarginProperty, new Thickness(3, 3, 3, 3));
    textBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, textBinding);

    FrameworkElementFactory comboBox = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ComboBox));
    comboBox.SetValue(ComboBox.MarginProperty, new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1));
    comboBox.SetBinding(ComboBox.TextProperty, textBinding);
    comboBox.SetValue(ComboBox.SelectedValuePathProperty, "Key");
    comboBox.SetValue(ComboBox.DisplayMemberPathProperty, "Value");

    Binding itemsSourceBinding = new Binding();
    itemsSourceBinding.Source = itemsSource;
    comboBox.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, itemsSourceBinding);

    comboBoxColumn.CellTemplate = new DataTemplate();
    comboBoxColumn.CellTemplate.VisualTree = textBlock;
    comboBoxColumn.CellEditingTemplate = new DataTemplate();
    comboBoxColumn.CellEditingTemplate.VisualTree = comboBox;

    return comboBoxColumn;
}
```

}

Comment: what's the bounty for? isn't Meleak already helping you? seems like he put quite some effort in?!

Comment: Maybe he wants to reward @Meleak for helping him...

Comment: @Stephen well then I'd encourage that. Just wasn't so sure if answers posted before the bounty were elegible to receive the bounty, the faq isn't quite so clear about that...

Comment: I believe that answers posted before the bounty can be awarded, but will not be *automatically* awarded.  Hope I am not wrong.  :-)

Comment: Still didn't have a solution that worked as per the original question.  Was looking for @Meleak or someone else to post a solution that solved the original problem.  That's been done now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**
You can use a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` and set `SelectedValueBinding` to get it to work the way you want. So just change the method you have to this one and it should work

```
public DataGridColumn GetNewComboBoxColumn(string header,
                                           string bindingPath,
                                           object itemsSource)
{
    DataGridComboBoxColumn comboBoxColumn = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
    comboBoxColumn.Header = header;
    comboBoxColumn.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
    comboBoxColumn.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";

    Binding binding = new Binding();
    binding.Path = new PropertyPath(bindingPath);
    comboBoxColumn.SelectedValueBinding = binding;

    Binding itemsSourceBinding = new Binding();
    itemsSourceBinding.Source = itemsSource;
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(comboBoxColumn, DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSourceProperty, itemsSourceBinding);

    return comboBoxColumn;
}
```

Comment: Great I'm almost there.  I actually have a Dictionary that I'm binding to so I've set the ComboBox.DisplayMemberPathProperty and ComboBox.SelectedValuePathProperty.  However my itemsSource contains only the Dictionary Key so the key (an int) is getting displayed. What I want to actually display the Dictionary Value. What do I need to change?

Comment: @openshac: Updated my answer with an example of how to use a `Dictionary<int, string>` as ItemsSource for the `ComboBox`

Comment: @Meleak: Thanks for that, that's exactly what I had as well.  Unfortunately the CellTemplate still shows the Key (int) of the Dictionary and not the Value (string).

Comment: @openshac: When DisplayMemberPath is set to Value, then Value is what should be displayed so I can't say what your problem is. I can upload a working sample project for you later today

Comment: @Meleak: Agreed the CellEditingTemplate has it's DisplayMemberPath.  However the CellTemplate does not, which I think is the cause of the problem. It's just a TextBlock showing the Key (not the value).

Comment: @openshac: What's is your `Dictionary` value type? You source property should be of the same type. In my example, I've used string. The way I see it, the `TextBlock` shouldn't have anything to do with the `Dictionary` or have I missunderstood your scenario?

Comment: @Meleak: Thought it would be easier if I posted my full code (in the original post) so you can see what I mean, hopefully it should be clearer :-)

Comment: @openshac: Updated my answer. The easiest way to get it working is to use a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` and use the `SelectedValueBinding`